# Ambiguious Ternary Statements

Tags: php

Working on a simple project, the objective is to find whether or not it is a leap year. In PHP, I attempted to use a ternary rather then the standard elseif statements.

```
$year = 2000;
$is_leapYear = ($year%400 == 0)? true: ($year%100 == 0)? false: ($year % 4 == 0);
echo ($year % 400 == 0) .'.'. ($year % 100 == 0) .'.'. ($year % 4 ==0);
echo $year . ' is ' . ($is_leapYear ? '' : 'not') . ' a leap year';
```

I discovered that this doesn't work because of a lack of parenthesis. Here is the correct solution:

```
$is_leapYear = ($year % 400 == 0)? true: (($year % 100 == 0)? false: ($year%4 == 0));
```

My question is why do ternary operators need parenthesis on the top `true` or `false` branch? I don't think the above code is ambiguous.

Comment: Caution: The [ternary operator is left-associative](http://phpsadness.com/sad/30).

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea a about the left-associative property. That is PHP sadness indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for such complicated code. PHP's date() can return whether it's a leap year or not:

```
$is_leap_year = (bool) date('L', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year));
```

See [manual here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: Where `$year` isn't a year value, it's a numerical UNIX timestamp.

Comment: Just realised. Corrected the answer.

Comment: oh nice, its a PHP class so I guess implementing algorithms for the sake of algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

There is no ambiguity and sadness of PHP Ternary Operator:

```
<?php
// on first glance, the following appears to output 'true'
echo (true?'true':false?'t':'f');

// however, the actual output of the above is 't'
// this is because ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right

// the following is a more obvious version of the same code as above
echo ((true ? 'true' : false) ? 't' : 'f');

// here, you can see that the first expression is evaluated to 'true', which
// in turn evaluates to (bool)true, thus returning the true branch of the
// second ternary expression.
?>
```

[SOURCE](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Your code executes like this:

```
$year = 2000;
$is_leapYear = (($year%400 == 0)? true: ($year%100 == 0)) ? false: ($year%4==0);
echo $is_leapYear;
```

LEFT-to-RIGHT

Comment: who down-voted I really want to know because your note adding some value!!! you also downvoted on other posts of me few minutes ago!!! it seems that you are monitoring me!!!

Comment: Upvoted; This explains why the asker's expression using a ternary operator did not work, which is valuable information.